# Moment date format changing from Node to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs, mongoose-schema

I am creating an app in node js and saving date to Mongo DB, the datatype of Mongoose, I used to save is Date.

```
  moment.locale("pt");
  today= moment().startOf("day").format();
```

The date is printing like `2019-05-27T00:00:00-03:00`

But when it is saving and I am trying to retrieve the date it is coming from mongo db like `2019-05-27T03:00:00.000Z`

Now the comparison didn't work. So I am finding data based on this date and it is not working.

I am using locale for Brazil.I am keeping the user details day wise from 00:00 to next 24 hours and doing a luck draw of users. So I have huge database and want to filter data based on today date. So I need date should be saved in local timezone i.e. Brazil.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about normalizing the dates before you insert them into the DB via `moment UTC` (and also using `.valueOf()` to get ms) and once you output them - convert to the relevant locale

Comment: How can you please explain ?

Comment: @Aviad, I need to save the date in local time without time, I am doing lucky draw for each day.

Comment: wdym by "local time without time"? just the date?

Comment: @Aviad Yes I am keeping the user details day wise from 00:00 to next 24 hours and doing a luck draw of users. So I have huge database and want to filter data based on today date. So I need date should be saved in local timezone i.e. Brazil.

Comment: ok, you can do the following - get the time in `UTC`, move it to Brazil locale, change it to the start of the day, and get the milliseconds of it (`.valueOf`) - then store

Comment: @Aviad, Can you let me know how I can move it to Brazil locale once I have date in UTC ? I tried parseZone and locale but not working.

Comment: yes, I'd use `moment`. Will post an answer

Comment: How are you comparing the two? The dates you mentioned in your question are essentially same. `2019-05-27T00:00:00-03:00` is exact same moment in time as `2019-05-27T03:00:00.000Z`. As long as you create a moment instance from these strings, the comparison should yield 'equal'. However, if you try to compare them as strings, yeah they will seem unequal.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving to `UTC`, then changing the locale, then mutating the date to match the day's beginning and then storing as ms:

```js
const d = moment
          .utc() // Get the UTC time
          .locale('pt_BR') // Change locale to Brazil
          .startOf('day') // Go back in time to current date @ 00:00:00
          .valueOf() // Get ms value

// store d in the database
```

Comment: moment
          .utc()
          .locale('pt_BR')``` is not changing the locale to brazil.

Comment: maybe `locale('br')` ?